# Prevent screen.findByX without an await with eslint no-restricted-syntax?

Tags: javascript, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree

This [medium article](https://medium.com/@_kbremner/make-eslint-do-the-work-adding-custom-rules-b83c2a1879a6) shows me how to prevent an `await` preceding a property:

```js
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",
  {
    "message": "promise.then is unnecessary when using async/await",
    "selector": "AwaitExpression[argument.callee.property.name=\" then\"]"
  }
]
```

But I want the opposite, I want to restrict these:

```
expect(screen.findByRole(...))....;
screen.findByRole(...);
```

but allow these:

```
expect(await screen.findByRole(...))....;
await screen.findByRole(...);
```

I tried this under my overrides for test files:

```js
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",
  {
    "message": "Find By queries must be followed by an await",
    "selector": ":not(AwaitExpression[argument.callee.property.name=/findBy.*/])"
  }
]
```

But now every line is showing that error. I also tried putting `*` in front, hoping it would allow anything (the `*`) unless is was followed by my banned syntax expression, but no dice.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This AST selector seems to work:

`:not(AwaitExpression) > CallExpression[callee.property.name=/^findBy.*$/]`

The selector looks for direct children of non-await expressions that  call a method beginning with `findBy...`.

The whole rule may look like:

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",
  {
    "message": "findBy... queries must be preceded by an await",
    "selector": ":not(AwaitExpression) > CallExpression[callee.property.name=/^findBy.*$/]"
  }
]
```

##### Standalone Functions

For function calls that aren't called by objects (e.g. just `findByRole` instead of `screen.findByRole`), you can omit the `property` nested attribute in the selector, like so:

`:not(AwaitExpression) > CallExpression[callee.name=/^findBy.*$/]`

If you want to match both Standalone functions and Method functions, you can have two separate rules, or combine them with the `:matches(...)` selector.

#### Try it out

You can [try it out here on the ESLint Playground](https://eslint.org/play/#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).