# Forbid using screen outside of it/test with eslint's 'no-restricted-syntax'

Tags: javascript, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm back trying to get `'no-restricted-syntx to work'`. I've not got [Prevent screen.findByX without an await with eslint no-restricted-syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71967980/prevent-screen-findbyx-without-an-await-with-eslint-no-restricted-syntax) to work, but I have another scenario where I need it. I noticed we were getting some issue related to a similar issue, with the explanation [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/371#issuecomment-492762406):

> You shouldn't render outside of a test()/it() block. The JSDOM env is global (shared between tests) and the cleanup in the inner describe() is cleaning up the DOM.

I have this kinda code:

```js
beforeEach(async() => {
  render(<MyLovelyComponent />);
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getAllByText('dddd'));
});
```

And I've like to warn/error on that `screen` being used there.

My attempt at writing the `'no-restricted-syntax'` selector, based off some stuff from [How to forbid a specific named function with ESlint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977713/how-to-forbid-a-specific-named-function-with-eslint) as well,  looks like:

```js
'no-restricted-syntax':[
  'error',
  {
    message: 'No screen outside of it',
    selector: `FunctionCall[name!="it"] MemberExpression[object.name="screen"]`
  },
],
```

Here is my current attempt:

https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/53f841902242b436121b51ab4673344f/320bfaf0ac537c90fd501a0a969c79c1bb23f838

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this, I ended up double checking the AST Explorer and came up with:

```js
'no-restricted-syntax':[
  'error',
  {
    message: 'No screen inside beforeEach',
    selector: `CallExpression[callee.name="beforeEach"] MemberExpression[object.name="screen"]`
  },
],
```

I still haven't got a way to block in in other ways not involving `beforeEach` but it's a start!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout), linter I'm working on for this purpose, it much more powerful then `no-restricted-syntax`. The code looks like:

```js
export const report = () => `Avoid using 'screen.__()' outside of 'it()'`;

export const fix = noop;

export const include = () => [
    'screen.__(__args)',
];

export const filter = (path) => {
    while (path = path.parentPath) {
        if (!path.isCallExpression())
            continue;
        
        if (path.get('callee').isIdentifier({name: 'it'}))
            return false;
    }
    
    console.log(`screen.__() found in place different from 'it()'`);
    
    
    return true;
}
```

Check out in [Putout Editor](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/d0a47d52d42cca15a5e7c0cf039a169c/41f7af411545e2544409ce2821fb8e282703a9cb) or run code snippet to see how it works:

```js
const source = `
    beforeEach(async() => {
        render(<MyLovelyComponent />);
        await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getAllByText('dddd'));
    });

    it('hello', async() => {
        render(<MyLovelyComponent />);
        await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getAllByText('abc'));
    });
`;

const {places} = putout(source, {
   plugins: [
      ['screen', {
          report: () => `Avoid using 'screen.__()' outside of 'it()'`,
          fix: () => {},
          include: () => [
              'screen.__(__args)',
          ],

          filter: (path) => {
              while (path = path.parentPath) {
              if (!path.isCallExpression())
                  continue;

              if (path.get('callee').isIdentifier({name: 'it'}))
                  return false;
              }
        
              return true;
            }
        }]
    ]
});

console.log(places);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@putout/bundle@1.7/bundle/putout-iife.js"></script>
```

It can also be used with ESLint with help of [`eslint-plugin-putout`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-putout)